# how to show plane text with break lines and space in bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

i read text file and show it on modal 
but the modal remove all spaces and new line 
even i can see my text file in correct format in Inspect window
How i can show text in correct format ?

[image]

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MDAshik the image show anything that you want . really you dont understand my question ????

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clearly understandable, i have done something looking at your image . I hope this could help you in something you are trying to achieve.

Try coding in the following way,

```
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>TCP 0.0.0.0.80  <span> 0.0.0.0</span></p>
    <p>TCP 0.0.0.0.81  <span> 0.0.0.0</span></p>
    <p>TCP 0.0.0.0.82  <span> 0.0.0.0</span></p>
    <p>TCP 0.0.0.0.83  <span> 0.0.0.0</span></p>
    <p>TCP 0.0.0.0.84  <span> 0.0.0.0</span></p>
    <p>TCP 0.0.0.0.85  <span> 0.0.0.0</span></p>
    <p>TCP 0.0.0.0.86  <span> 0.0.0.0</span></p>
</div>
```

the styling goes like this;

```
<style>
    .modal-body{
        width:70%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
        .modal-body p{
        display:block;
    }
        .modal-body span{
        float:right;
    }
</style>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I read a text file and show in modal view , all text file are not in same format ...

Comment: Is there any link to your demo that i can view about what actually you are trying to achieve. Still your question lacks clear visualization to  answer us.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text you want to not wrap inside `<pre></pre>` tags, like this:

```html
<pre>TCP 0.0.0.0.80   0.0.0.0
TCP 0.0.0.0.81   0.0.0.0
TCP 0.0.0.0.82   0.0.0.0
TCP 0.0.0.0.83   0.0.0.0
TCP 0.0.0.0.84   0.0.0.0
TCP 0.0.0.0.85   0.0.0.0
TCP 0.0.0.0.86   0.0.0.0</pre>
```